# Off-topic flag declined because of strange reason

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446582/would-you-choose-a-brand-new-car-or-go-for-a-second-hand-one) is the question

and my off-topic flag declined because of the reason

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

so, moderators shouldn't be aware of **this** kind of nonsense in stack overflow?

Comment: Perhaps the mod saw it as already closed?

Comment: then why is it enabled to flag a question which is already closed can be my next question

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't closed when you flagged it, but was closed when the moderator reviewed your flag.  (Though I'd expect the flag to be automatically considered helpful in that case, to avoid wasting a mod's time.)

Comment: what kind of flag did you use?  That would have an impact on the answer?  [animuson's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261873/250725) explains why.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You used a custom moderator flag to indicate that it was off-topic. **Do not do that.** Use the canonical close reason that corresponds to the reason it should be closed by using the "it should be closed for another reason" option in the flag menu. This sends the flag to an appropriate place where it can be handled by the community, rather than throwing it into a huge pile of custom flags.

The custom flag reason is **not** for general close requests and any time you use it for such a reason, you should expect it to be declined, whether it was a valid flag or not.