# Closing Already Answered Questions With Positive Scores

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, old-questions

Occasionally, I come across Question that have been answered with Very High Positive Score, that are poor question.
I've frequently come across these questions several times in the review audits as well.

Generally when I see questions, with no MCVE, or attempt to research or answer the question they are considered poor questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516119/regular-expression-to-match-characters-at-beginning-of-line-only)

I've noticed questions that are closed don't tend to appear in the review queue audits.

Closing this question would not delete it so it wouldn't affect reputation.

Yet, When I flag them for moderation they are denied?
I wanted to open a discussion to understand what questions deserve to be left open and closed.  Seeing as they affect other parts of the community.

Is there a reason why this question should not be closed?

Comment: "When I flag them for moderation" is the key phrase. Don't do that. You have enough rep to cast close votes. Do that.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan already established questions do not go through additional reviews.  If the community has failed to properly close a question they are in need of moderation

Comment: @johnny5 there would be a need of citation for that. I was under the inverse impression myself, I think I've read somewhere that a close vote will bump them in a queue. In any event, without hard *proof* that they won't, you should still vote to close.

Comment: I don't believe that is correct. If you vote to close a question, no matter its age, it goes into the Close Votes review queue. See the discussion here: [Is closing old questions a gigantic waste of time and effort?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254402)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier hmm interesting I didn’t think of the close votes queue I could be mistaken then I’ll need to research how that works

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan you are correct, but for questions with more than 100 views won’t they be ages away in 4 days,  seeing as the queue is on average 9K of question won’t it be highly improbable that it would even be viewed in the queue by others?

Comment: Well, that's why I linked to that question using the title :). Still, as Felix says in his answer, it's not appropriate to involve moderators.

Comment: possibly a better duplicate is [Off-topic flag declined because of strange reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261873/839601)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Yet, When I flag them for moderation they are denied?

Rightfully so. Custom moderator flags are not there to handle things we can handle ourselves. In this case, you can vote to close it if you stumble upon an old question that does not fit in today's standards. That regex question is arguably off-topic.

If you feel very strongly that a question should be closed, you can also go over at [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chatroom to attract attention on a question. There is a way to do so, read the rules over there.

Keep in mind that folks in SOCVR are very experienced and level headed, they will evaluate your claim and may or may not agree with you. Simply asking for a question to be closed does not amount to it getting closed.

Comment: I should have refined my question, but I really just wanted a way for these to be removed from the auditing system

Comment: Note that SOCVR is _not_ intended for old questions. If you have an old question that shows no new activity, vote to close it, but don't bring it up in SOCVR.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be "flagging for moderation" regular questions - you can vote to close, upvote, downvote and edit just fine yourself.

Note that "how to..." questions *do not require* MCVE. They may be downvoted if no research shown or sometimes closed for other reasons (duplicate, too broad...)

In case linked as an example ([Regular expression to match characters at beginning of line only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516119/regular-expression-to-match-characters-at-beginning-of-line-only)) the question is clear and definitely useful and visited a lot (with 110,836 views). I don't see reason why that question needs  to be closed.

Comment: The question is clear, but it shows no attempt to solve.  The majority of question that ask the community to write code for them with no attempt to solve the issues themselves get closed.

Comment: To be more exact my main concern is to remove these questions from the audits

Comment: @johnny5 you should probably ask new question instead... There is no indication of your concern in you question nor accepted answer. Note that I personally see no reason why this question would be bad audit or should be closed (unless there is better duplicate).

Comment: For every question like this you can find 3 that have been closed. I guess you can state if you don’t know you should skip it.  But the majority of users would fail this as an audit

Comment: @johnny5 there is currently no close reason (except duplicate) that fits such question. So I see no problem if one fails audit by voting to close as "missing MCVE" or "too broad" on this question.