# How is this question not considered low quality?

Tags: discussion, questions, declined-flags

I flagged [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127662/realtime-web-notification-by-using-angular-and-php) as low quality a while ago. Today I was browsing through my flags and noticed it was declined by a moderator. After reviewing it again I still believe this is a low quality question for a couple of reasons:

1. The user has been a member for 6 years and 5 months, so the likelihood that there's no effort being put in and they're simply looking for a quick answer is quite high; this isn't a new user.
2. There was no code provided and the question doesn't seem to pivot towards there being code that I could easily ask to see.
3. It's got a low word count and what is written within these words is confusing/misleading, specifically *'I am getting codes all with node support'* and *'Web socket is working localhost. but i do not know how to run server file in live server.'* At the time of reading this, I was considering an edit, but I didn't think there was a simple route to improving the question so it was actually answerable, so I flagged it.

Could you help me to understand where my logic here went wrong and this wasn't a low quality question?

Dashboard Image:

[image: Dashboard Image]

Comment: Are you sure that flag is declined? Not disputed? It sat in two queues: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/19608448 and https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19607310

Comment: @rene I added screen shot showing decline.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265573/1233251

Comment: I would not qualify that post as low quality to be honest. Flag for closure as unclear / too broad. Low quality works for gibbersh, not for bad english grammar posts

Comment: @rene I mean there might be a question in that post, it's just super hard to make out, I think it would be classified as gibberish in my parse :/ I've flagged for closure, but it urks me that the flag is 'declined' as it makes it feel like you were completely wrong.

Comment: sure, but if a mod sees socket.io and node and some other keywords they are more likely to err on the save side

Comment: Moderators do not want to delete Q+A like that by themselves, they consider it to be a community duty.  That rarely comes to a good end, the VLQ review queue doesn't have volunteers.  You don't have enough rep to vote to close yet, the automatic cleanup (aka roomba) will take care of it eventually.   Favor a downvote to help it make up its mind about it.  Looks like you already did today, you were the first to vote.  Which is why the roomba didn't do it yet.  DVs are now the best tool to get rid of crap.

Comment: What the site considers gibberish looks like this: "asl;dl;dsl;b as;slwo b a;;;a;a sl b alsklddkd rrrrrrrr.....rrrrr!" It's not enough for it to not be understandable, it has to be outright nonsense.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with the other comments, I think unclear is a better fit than VLQ. Unclear is like, "I can tell you're trying to ask _something_, but I can't tell what it is and I don't think anyone else will be able to either", and VLQ is more like "It looks like you accidentally posted this while banging your head against the keyboard."

Comment: The official purpose of the "very low quality" flag is far more narrow than just posts whose quality is very low. It's one of the many, many ways in which using this site is confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Off-topic flag declined because of strange reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261871/off-topic-flag-declined-because-of-strange-reason)

Comment: We've all been there (well, at least some of us). The question is not low quality, it's just too broad (waaay too broad).

Comment: The link now goes to a 404 page. Maybe it was deleted?

Comment: @ArchieBaer Yes, the question is now deleted.

Comment: Did you not get the memo? We accept any old garbage these days. The VLQ flag is completely misleading these days, in my opinion that question is very poor quality wise and should be burned with fire. You are right to feel aggrieved, in the end I give up flagging dog piles as VLQ and switched to downvoting and using "Unclear" or "Too Broad" instead.

Comment: @BSMP for cases like you describe ("asl;dl;dsl;b") it is recommended to use rude/abusive flag, [see explanation here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773)

Comment: The VLQ flag is pretty much useless. You can use it on link only answers if you want (but be aware you'll be leaving behind a auto-downvote even if the flag is marked helpful due to the post being edited/fixed). But you can also go NAA there (doesn't leave the downvote and doesn't get (in-)validated by edits, except from review). Total gibberish can be nuked with R/A. I'd suggest removing the flag from the UI or give it a proper meaning, but that might take 6-8.

Comment: @HansPassant The VLQ queue is actually doing decently well reviewer wise, but questions don't end up there to begin with. It only handles VLQ and NAA flags on answers.

Comment: @gnat Not a duplicate. In that case, the user raised a mod flag. The questioner here raised a VLQ flag

Comment: @Machavity same thing really. VLQ flags on questions go to mod queue after some (configurable) delay, about 15 minutes at SO if memory serves. Moderator declined following the same reasoning as explained in [duplicate answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261873/839601): "Use the canonical close reason..."

Comment: @gnat That's good enough as an answer, probably. Certainly less confusing than a dupe closure.

Comment: @gnat Having read a few comments, might be a better dupe of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/2370483) then

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a couple of things at play here, one of which isn't all that obvious

1. Don't use VLQ for questions unless it's blatantly obvious junk. To be perfectly honest, **I wouldn't use VLQ for questions at all** myself. As [Shog9 noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/2370483)

   > VLQ flags on questions that should be closed just create unnecessary overhead

   It's not obvious, but VLQ is mod-heavy on reviews. Raising one is almost like raising a mod flag (but not quite). This isn't obvious unless you hang around Meta or mods, tho. Your chances of a decline of a VLQ flag on a question are much higher than they would be on an answer.
2. **Raise flags for closure, even if you don't have Close privileges yet**. One of SO's best-kept secrets (don't tell Tim Post I told you about this) is that if you find a question that's bad, **flagging for closure is always preferred**. I mean, if you're in the hilariously misnamed Help and Improvement (where people expect *you* to edit crap into good questions) I always open the question and vote to close instead of clicking the VLQ link (which just keeps churning it back and forth). What your decline should tell you (but doesn't because it's a secret) is that mods don't generally close questions when the community can do that directly.